# 3D array output null in java?

Tags: java, arrays, 3d

So I just learned doing arrays in 1D and 2D in java, but I don't seem to do 3D correct since the output seems to show **null** like this:

> One null null
> null Two null
> null null Three
>
> One null null
> null Two null
> null null Three
>
> One null null
> null Two null
> null null Three

---

I want it like this:

> One Two Three
> One Two Three
> One Two Three
>
> One Two Three
> One Two Three
> One Two Three
>
> One Two Three
> One Two Three
> One Two Three

---

**SOLVED** *(changed the format of the array to make it simplier for me as a beginner.)*

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[][][] numbers = {
                                {{"One", "Two", "Three"}, {"Four", "Five", "Six"},
                                {"Seven", "Eight", "Nine"}, {"Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve"}}
                                };

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println();
            for(int j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.println();
                for(int k = 0; k < numbers[i][j].length; k++)
                {
                    System.out.print(numbers[i][j][k] + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You assign 9 values, but you should assign 27 to have them all filled. All those coordinates you didn't assign a value to, remain null

Comment: And perhaps you should assign the 27 values to `numbers`, not  to the non-existing `cars`...

Comment: @Mihe
Yeah sorry, my bad, I forgot to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to fill your arrays correctly. A 3D-array in Java is just an array of 2D-arrays and a 2D-array is just an array of (1D-)arrays.

You can fill a given (1D-)array `row` of length 3 by assigning values to its elements, that is

```
row[0] = "One";
row[1] = "Two";
row[2] = "Three";
```

Given a 2D-Array `matrix` you can do this for every single row:

```
for (String[] row : matrix) {
    row[0] = "One";
    row[1] = "Two";
    row[2] = "Three";
}
```

Now, you have an array `numbers` of those matrices:

```
for (String[][] matrix : numbers) {
    for (String[] row : matrix) {
        row[0] = "One";
        row[1] = "Two";
        row[2] = "Three";
    }  
}
```

I've used for-each-loops here. They can be turned into normal for-loops easily:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    String[][] matrix = numbers[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        String[] row = matrix[j];
        row[0] = "One";
        row[1] = "Two";
        row[2] = "Three";
    }
}
```

From that you can substitute `row` by `matrix[j]` which gives you

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    String[][] matrix = numbers[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        matrix[j][0] = "One";
        matrix[j][1] = "Two";
        matrix[j][2] = "Three";
    }
}
```

Of course, you can substitute `matrix`, too. This time by `numbers[i]`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++) {
        numbers[i][j][0] = "One";
        numbers[i][j][1] = "Two";
        numbers[i][j][2] = "Three";
    }
}
```

**Update**

You can directly integrate this in your code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[][][] numbers = new String[3][3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++) {
                numbers[i][j][0] = "One";
                numbers[i][j][1] = "Two";
                numbers[i][j][2] = "Three";
            }
        }        

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println();
            for(int j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.println();
                for(int k = 0; k < numbers[i][j].length; k++)
                {
                    System.out.print(numbers[i][j][k] + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since I'm new I've a hard time understanding what "for (String[] row : matrix)" really means so therefore I changed it to make it more simplier for me as you can see in the post I just updated.

Comment: for-each is really just that: for each element in `matrix` repeat ... See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33232565/19657183 for a very good answer.

Comment: Alright, I just learned for each but sadly I do not understand 3D array any good, 1D and 2D I understand but 3D is more complex for me. But thanks for putting effort into it!

Comment: Take your time. Try to find good resources, Stackoverflow is neither intended to be nor is it the best place to learn Java :-)

Comment: I understand, would it be possible to see how you would do it (whole code) so I can analyze it bit by bit for better understanding? I can only make it work with curly brackets on 3D array since I only need to initialize it like > "String[][][] names = {{{"name", "name" etc...}}} < I don't need to do it index by index myself because for each do it automatically for me. But it's totally okey if you don't wanna do it nor have time for it. Thanks anyways :)